# Need help understanding the F# class syntax

Tags: f#

This is a very elementary question about the F# class syntax. Here is a little code to illustrate my problem.

```
type AClass() as self =
    member this.Something = printfn "Hello"
```

Basically from what I have read the "as self" will create a name to the current instance which can be used in the entire class (like "this" in C# or Java). But "member this.Something" will do the same thing, only that the scope is limited to the method body. I guess I can see when you would use which syntax. The "as self" one can be used if you need it in the constructor or something and you can use the other one if you dont need it in the constructor.

But why do I have to use the "member this.Something" syntax even if I used the "as self" one? Why does it give me an error if I just write "member Something"? What have I missed?

Take care,
Kerr

Comment: Realistically, this is just a small bit of duplication as most of the time you want to avoid the `as self`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scope of `as self` is the whole class, while scope of `this.Something` is just an individual method. You don't often need `as self` since using `this.Something` is adequate.

Regarding why you need `this.` in member declaration, I think it's a natural choice since in F# classes you often have let bounds and static methods as well. Having `self` as default would cause confusion and misuse.

Here is an example using `as self` in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233205.aspx), which is not common IMO:

```
type MyClass2(dataIn) as self =
   let data = dataIn
   do
       self.PrintMessage()
   member this.PrintMessage() =
       printf "Creating MyClass2 with Data %d" data
```

Comment: So its more or less the case of harmless duplication? Thinking about it makes me realize that its probably better to be consistent then to have a really smart compiler that could determine when "this." should be required or not. Avoids confusion. Think I will just use the "as self" when I need it in the constructor and use "this." elsewhere. Thanks :).

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you've got all the differences between global 'as xxx' and member 'yyy.' instance binding sorted out. So I guess the answer to your answer has to be it's "by design".

Folks will argue that there is a deliberate rational behind this "by design" choice, but after 4 years of programming F#, my favorite language by far, I have personally not found it very helpful in any regard.

I suspect that the real reason the language requires explicit instance bindings to variables is because is more closely reflects the underlying .NET CIL implementation. That is, languages like C# bind "this" to the instance of a class definition as a feature. Under-the-hood, both static and instance methods of a class are called in the same manner using the Call and CallVirt opcodes, where in the case of instance methods the address of "this" is loaded as the first argument to the call.

But we've certainly ventured into the territory of taste and opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is duplication at all. `self`'s visibility to the entire class is a by-product of F#'s "intelligent" compilation of primary constructors. The constructor's arguments/bindings can be implicitly compiled to both local and member (class-level) fields. The `as identifier` syntax merely facilitates `this` references within that mutant context. I'd venture to guess, if unused, it's compiled away. Otherwise, all you've done is stored an extra reference to `this` as a member field (which would seem bizarre in another language, such as C#).